# Merge duplicate keys in associative array BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, associative-array, bash-array

I've got an array that contains duplicate items, e.g.

```
THE_LIST=(
"'item1' 'data1 data2'"
"'item1' 'data2 data3'"
"'item2' 'data4'"
)
```

Based on the above, I want to create an associative array that would assign `itemN` as key and `dataN` as value.

My code iterates over the list, and assigns key => value like this (the additional function is shortened, as it performs some additional jobs on the list):

```
function get_items(){
    KEY=$1
    VALUES=()
    shift $2
    for VALUE in "$@"; do
        VALUES[${#VALUES[@]}]="$VALUE"
    done
}

declare -A THE_LIST
for ((LISTID=0; LISTID<${#THE_LIST[@]}; LISTID++)); do
    eval "LISTED_ITEM=(${THE_LIST[$LISTID]})"
    get_items "${LISTED_ITEM[@]}"
    THE_LIST=([$KEY]="${VALUES[@]}")
done
```

when I print the array, I'm getting something like:

```
item1: data1 data2
item1: data2 data3
item2: data4
```

but instead, I want to get:

```
item1: data1 data2 data3
item2: data4
```

Cannot find a way of merging the duplicate keys as well as removing duplicate values for the key.

What would be the approach here?

***UPDATE***

The actual code is:

```
THE_LIST=(
"'item1' 'data1 data2'"
"'item1' 'data2 data3'"
"'item2' 'data4'"
)

function get_backup_locations () {
  B_HOST="$2"
  B_DIRS=()
  B_DIR=()
  shift 2

  for B_ITEM in "$@"; do
    case "$B_ITEM" in
      -*) B_FLAGS[${#B_FLAGS[@]}]="$B_ITEM" ;;
      *) B_DIRS[${#B_DIRS[@]}]="$B_ITEM" ;;
    esac
  done

  for ((B_IDX=0; B_IDX<${#B_DIRS[@]}; B_IDX++)); do
    B_DIR=${B_DIRS[$B_IDX]}

    ...do stuff here...

  done
}

function get_items () {
  for ((LOCIDY=0; LOCIDY<${#LOCATIONS[@]}; LOCIDY++)); do
    eval "LOCATION=(${LOCATIONS[$LOCIDY]})"
    get_backup_locations "${LOCATION[@]}"
    THE_LIST=([$B_HOST]="${B_DIR[@]}")
  done | sort | uniq
}
```

when printing the array with:

```
for i in "${!THE_LIST[@]}"; do
    echo "$i : ${THE_LIST[$i]}"
done
```

I get

```
item1: data1 data2
item1: data2 data3
item2: data4
```

Comment: Your code as given won't work at all  - `THE_LIST` is already a normal array, so you can't redeclare it as an associative array, and even if you could, you're overwriting it each time in the loop with `THE_LIST=([$KEY]="${VALUES[@]}")`.

Comment: @muru, so, by what you're saying, I cannot convert an array into associative array, or just not this way?

Comment: I'm saying that the code has no relation to the output that you say you're getting.

Comment: In addition to that, clarification is needed as to what the format of the keys and values can be. What characters can be in the keys, for example? Spaces? Can either include more quotes inside them?

Comment: I've updated my question with snippet of the acutal code. The keys/values are alphanumeric, they do not include quotes or spaces.

Comment: This is not helping your question, but have you taken a look at `python`? Complex stuff like this is often easy as hell in `python`.

Comment: @Panki, yes, Python or perl might be better approach here, however, I'm adding additional feature to an existing bash script, thus the pain.. it's simply too large to rewrite the whole thing in time. if I don't find a way, I may just as well use another language for the task.

Comment: @Bart You poor soul!

Comment: @Panki, there, there!

Comment: I’m so glad that my employer encourages converting long (>100 LoC) Bash scripts to Python! This is clearly a task that suits Python way better than any shell script, because ultimately `THE_LIST` is a hash map (associative array) to a list (normal array). In JSON it’s like `{"item1": ["data1", "data2"]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keys and values are guaranteed to be purely alphanumerical, something like this might work:

```bsh
declare -A output

make_list() {
  local IFS=" "
  declare -A keys                  # variables declared in a function are local by default
  for i in "${THE_LIST[@]}"
  do 
    i=${i//\'/}                    # since everything is alphanumeric, the quotes are useless
    declare -a keyvals=($i)        # split the entry, filename expansion isn't a problem
    key="${keyvals[0]}"            # get the first value as the key
    keys["$key"]=1                 # and save it in keys
    for val in "${keyvals[@]:1}"
    do                             # for each value
      declare -A "$key[$val]=1"    # use it as the index to an array. 
    done                           # Duplicates just get reset.
  done

  for key in "${!keys[@]}"
  do                               # for each key
    declare -n arr="$key"          # get the corresponding array
    output["$key"]="${!arr[*]}"    # and the keys from that array, deduplicated
  done
}

make_list
declare -p output  # print the output to check
```

With the example input, I get this output:

```
declare -A output=([item1]="data3 data2 data1" [item2]="data4" )
```

The data items are out of order, but deduplicated.

---

Might be best to use Python with the `csv` module instead.

Comment: that does the job after some adjustments as bash version on target machine doesn't support namerefs declaration. thanks for pointers!

Comment: @Bart I'm curious: how did you fix that?

Comment: I was too fast being cheerful. this indeed works on a newer bash, but what I thought was a workaround, didn't work out well in the end. I'll most probably rewrite the script, worst case, put an RFC to update bash on a server ;)

Comment: @Bart are you on Bash 4.2, or something older?

Comment: that's bash 4.2.46

Comment: managed by simply creating an associative array from items ot the first array `THE_LIST+=(["${B_HOST}"]="${B_DIR[@]}")`, duplicates are not a big deal as they're just list of files to be removed from another list.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no whitespace in any of the values, this solution might work.  Use `awk` associative arrays to build up `declare -A` commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

THE_LIST=(
"'item1' 'data1 data2'"
"'item1' 'data2 data3'"
"'item2' 'data4'"
)

eval "$(\
  for i in "${THE_LIST[@]}"; do
    row=($(eval echo $i))
    echo "${row[@]}"
  done | awk '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) if (seen[$1] !~ $i) { seen[$1]=seen[$1]$i" " } }
    END { for (s in seen) print "declare -A new_list["s"]=\""seen[s] }' | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$/"/'
)"

for i in "${!new_list[@]}"; do
  echo "$i: ${new_list[$i]}"
done
```

This prints:

```
item2: data4
item1: data1 data2 data3
```

The order of the values is preserved, but the keys are reordered.  I couldn't figure out how to trim the trailing whitespace of an array entry in `awk` so I just used `sed` to replace it with a quote, but it's already a total hack to begin with.